# How to add weight to attribute inside feature vector for distance measure?

Tags: vector, machine-learning, distance

I am attempting to measure the distance between two feature vectors, but I want to give more importance to one attribute inside the feature vector beyond the rest. For example, if the vector I had below were filled with numeric features, how would I place more value on "taste"?

V = [ Taste, Smell, Feel, Look ]

I know I could just isolate that value and perform the distance measure on that, but I wasn't sure if that were the best way and if I would lose the "rest of the picture" by doing so. When I search for weighted distance measures, I tend to land on pages where the weight is just being used for normalization or standardization of the data which doesn't appear to carry the same meaning as what I would like.

Am I better off using the distance measure on the full vector and then applying something like KNN with weights later on?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try matrix multiply means you can give a weight matrix and just multiply this weight matrix with your data.